# Laravel WebSocket with Flutter

Tags: laravel, flutter, websocket

I'm trying to use laravel websocket in my flutter app

This is my laravel event code and I am broadcasting the event right here by passing the comment in the constructor

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class CommentEvent implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $comment;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public function __construct($comment)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel>
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [
            new Channel('comment-post'),
        ];
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return ['comment' => $this->comment];
    }
}
```

works fine when i connect locally to port 6001
and i am calling it here

```
public function comment(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $request->validate([
                'comment' => 'required'
            ]);
            $com = Comment::create([
                'user_id' => auth()->id(),
                'video_id' => $request->video_id,
                'content' => $request->comment,
            ]);
            if ($com) {
                event(new CommentEvent($request->comment));
                return response([
                    'message' => 'success',
                    'comment_count' => Comment::whereVideoId($request->video_id)->count(),
                    'comments' => $com,
                ], 200);
            } else {
                return response([
                    'message' => 'Cant comment'
                ], 500);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response([
                'message' => $e->getMessage()
            ], 500);
        }
    }
```

Now in my flutter code, I am lost i don't know how it connects, though I have this,
if i send an API request, it runs the event and that's where i am stuck , like i don't know how to retrieve the data from the socket

```
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;

class SocketClient {
  IO.Socket? socket;
  static SocketClient? _instance;

  SocketClient._internal() {
    socket = IO.io('http://172.20.10.4:3000', <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
      'autoConnect': false,
    });
    socket!.connect();
  }

  static SocketClient get instance {
    _instance ??= SocketClient._internal();
    return _instance!;
  }
}
```

All I am trying to do is to make a real time comment system, Any Suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: What is the WebSocket provider?

Comment: Please provide more info about the providers and config. You said `i connect locally to port 6001` but in mobile app you connect to socketio `http://172.20.10.4:3000`, meaning server writes data internally but you try to read data from the socket.io server.

Comment: @EhsanA.Kian using laravel websocket package

Comment: @Theofanis my bad, the socket is port 3000